# webView no funciona

Tags: android-studio, webview-android

Tengo un problema, mi aplicación no carga la URL http://www.fcv.org/SenInt/

el problema es q si me salgo de la aplicacion y cargo la misma URL desde el navegador del telefono, esta url si funciona.

Por esto creo que no es un error de la red, sino algun error dentro de la aplicación.

mi coóigo es este:

```
String urlMostrarGrafica = "http://www.fcv.org/SenInt/";
WebView wvPaginaPrincipal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_visualizador);

    wvPaginaPrincipal = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvPaginaPrincipal);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvPaginaPrincipal.loadUrl(urlMostrarGrafica);   
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

en el manifiest tengo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

podrian ayudarme a solucionar el error porfa.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido William, tiene un error tu código pero al parecer también puede ser el  layout, me parece que si te refieres a que no se despliega es porque esta siendo colapsada la vista, agrega tu layout. Te invito a realizar rl [tour] del sitio!

Answer (score 0):

Para el cargado de la página que revisando el código requiere ejecución de `JavaScript`, necesitas habilitar el `JavaScript` pero en la misma instancia del `WebView` (`wvPaginaPrincipal`), este sería el código correcto:

```
   wvPaginaPrincipal = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvPaginaPrincipal);

   //webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
   //WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
   //settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   wvPaginaPrincipal.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
   WebSettings settings = wvPaginaPrincipal.getSettings();
   settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   wvPaginaPrincipal.loadUrl(urlMostrarGrafica);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Oye, muchas gracias, con esto que me diste, lo he solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

NO ME CARGA ME SALE WEB NO SE PUDO CARGAR

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String urlMostrarGrafica = "http://www.licencia.com.pa/historial/historial.jsf/";
WebView wvPaginaPrincipal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wvPaginaPrincipal = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvPaginaPrincipal);

    //webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    //WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    //settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wvPaginaPrincipal.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = wvPaginaPrincipal.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wvPaginaPrincipal.loadUrl(urlMostrarGrafica);

}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Me paso ami tambien y el problema es que los webView solo cargan paginas que tengan https, en cambio si usa http no funciona creo que deberia haber una forma de cargar paginas que no usen https

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar

```
.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
```

a la instancia del WebView, tu lo agregaste a los settings de éste, pero no agregaste esos settings al WebView, solo bastaría con hacer

```
WebView.settings = settings
```

O aplicarlo directo

```
WebView.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
```

Además no entiendo por qué tienes dos instancias de WebView

```
wvPaginaPrincilal y webView
```

Además, estás creando el objeto del WebViewClient en webView, pero después intentas cargar la URL en el wvPaginaPrincilal, que no posee el cliente para manejar URL.

Y no es necesario el permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" \>
```